# How to read oData element in model?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, abap

Hi everyone I am new sap fiori developer.

I want to read oData element in default model? How can I do that?

For this example I wanna read Empid and Name
[Odata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gEel.png)

Comment: Share your code... or try `oData["EmployeeSet('1')"].Empname`

Comment: Thanks dude ,It worked for me . I have added my source code . // I use for mainview in sap fiori this.getView().getModel().oData["EmployeeSet('1')"].Empname; –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, next code will do the job :)

```
oData["EmployeeSet('1')"].Empname
```